# Call to a member function prepare() on null if __construct function is present

Tags: php, pdo, constructor

I've recently came across the need of pagination and I'll be using it quite a bit so I figured a class would be a perfect fit, for some reason when I try to use a `__construct` I get the fatal error:

> Call to a member function prepare() on null 
>       Thrown in '\App\Helpers\PaginationHelper.php' on line 31

Line 31 is this:

`$sth = $this->db->prepare('SELECT * FROM '. $this->table_name .' ORDER BY id LIMIT :page_first_result, :per_page');`

in the retrieveData function.

It's a big messy as I'm just beginning but for the life of me I can't figure out this error, I've read a few other questions that have the same error but they are all related to PDO not connecting, unlike this issue.

\Core\Model just extends a pdo connection

```
class PaginationHelper extends \Core\Model {

    public $results = [];
    public $tabs = '';
    public $set_data;
    public $table_name;
    public $results_per_page;

    public function __construct($sd){
        $this->set_data = $sd;
    }

    public function table_name($tn){
        $this->table_name = $tn;
    }

    public function results_per_page($rpp){
        $this->results_per_page = $rpp;
    }

    public function retrieveData($page_first_result, $per_page){
        $sth = $this->db->prepare('SELECT * FROM '. $this->table_name .' ORDER BY id LIMIT :page_first_result, :per_page');
        $sth->bindValue(':page_first_result', $page_first_result, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $sth->bindValue(':per_page', $per_page, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $sth->execute();

        return $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }

    public function getResults(){
        $number_of_results = $this->set_data;

        $this->number_of_pages = ceil( count($number_of_results) / $this->results_per_page);

        // determine which page number visitor is currently on
        if (!isset($_GET['pagination'])) {
          $this->page = 1;
        } else {
          $this->page = $_GET['pagination'];
        }

        $this_page_first_result = ($this->page - 1) * $this->results_per_page;

        $fetch = $this->retrieveData($this_page_first_result, $this->results_per_page);

        foreach($fetch as $data){
            $this->results[] = $data;
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function loopResults(){
        return $this->results;
    }

    public function getTabs(){

        if($this->page == 1){
            $this->back = $this->page;
        } else {
            $this->back = $this->page-1;
        }

        if($this->page == $this->number_of_pages){
            $this->next = $this->page;
        } else {
            $this->next = $this->page + 1;
        }

        $this->tabs .= '
            <div class="pagination">
                <a class="pagination__buttons-href" href="?pagination='.$this->back.'"><span class="pagination__buttons flaticon-keyboard-left-arrow-button"></span></a>
                <span class="pagination__current_page"> '. $this->page .' </span>
                <a class="pagination__buttons-href" href="?pagination='. $this->next .'"><span class="pagination__buttons flaticon-keyboard-right-arrow-button"></span></a>
            </div>
        ';

        return $this->tabs;
    }
}
```

Now, here is something interesting: If I remove the `__construct function`, and create a new method to put the $set_data property like below, everything works perfectly.

```
public function set_data($sd){
    $this->set_data = $sd;
}
```

This is how I'm calling the class:

This is how I'm calling the class with the function set_data:

```
$pagination = new PaginationHelper();
$pagination->set_data($array_data);
$pagination->table_name('recipe');
$pagination->results_per_page(20);
$pagination->getResults();
```

Comment: you need to initiate `$this->db` properly, maybe in the constructor. For now it's just an uninitialized (and undeclared) property

Comment: The \Core\Model passes the `$this->db` from its construct function in the database class.

Comment: the error message explicitly says otherwise. The parent constructor has to be called explicitly for it to be run at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you define your own constructor, the parent's constructor will not be called automatically.

Try doing this instead:

```
public function __construct($sd){
    parent::__construct();
    $this->set_data = $sd;
}
```

Direct quote from the documentation (http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php):

> Note: Parent constructors are not called implicitly if the child class defines a constructor. In order to run a parent constructor, a call to parent::__construct() within the child constructor is required. If the child does not define a constructor then it may be inherited from the parent class just like a normal class method (if it was not declared as private).

Answer (score 3):

When you extend a class and have a `__constructor()` function in it, you should call its parent's constructor as well:

```
parent::__construct();
```

If you skip this line, \Core\Model's constructor is never called. If you remove the constructor, it is called automatically.

Answer (score 1):

try this one

```
public function __construct($sd){
parent::__construct();
$this->set_data = $sd;
```

}

call the parent constructor manually